# Creating a Ruby Hash Map in a Functional Way

Tags: ruby, dictionary, functional-programming

I have an array I want to turn into a hash map keyed by the item and with an array of indices as the value. For example

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
```

would become

```
hsh = {"a": [0,3], "b": [1], "c": [2]}
```

I would like to do this in a **functional** way (rather than a big old for loop), but am a little stuck

```
lst = arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| [item, i] }
```

produces

```
[["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["a", 3]]
```

I then tried Hash[lst], but I don't get the array in the value and lose index 0

```
{"a"=>3, "b"=>1, "c"=>2}
```

How can I get my desired output in a functional way? I feel like it's something like

```
Hash[arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| [item, item[i] << i || [i] }]
```

But that doesn't yield anything.

Note: Trying to *not* do it this way

```
hsh = {}
arr.each.with_index do |item, index|
   if hsh.has_key?(item)
      hsh[item] << index
   else 
      hsh[item] = [index]
   end 
end
hsh
```

Comment: Edited - trying to avoid the code at the bottom.

Comment: Yup! Pretty obvious. Just trying to learn a different way of doing it.

Comment: Think about `group_by`.

Comment: In your original array, the elements are strings, in your desired outcome, the keys are symbols, but in none of your attempted solutions do you ever do anything to convert the keys from strings to symbols. Are they really supposed to be symbols? You say you want a hash "keyed by the item", but if the items are strings and the keys are symbols, then it is not really "keyed by the item", is it?

Answer (score 3):

Input

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
```

Code

```
p arr.map
      .with_index
      .group_by(&:first)
      .transform_values { |arr| arr.map(&:last) }
```

Output

```
{"a"=>[0, 3], "b"=>[1], "c"=>[2]}
```

Comment: is ruby cool enough to allow `.transform_values { |arr| arr.map(&:last) }` to be written as `.transform_values(&:map(&:last))`?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like to do this in a **functional** way (rather than a big old for loop), but am a little stuck
>
> ```
> lst = arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| [item, i] }
> ```
>
> produces
>
> ```
> [["a", 0], ["b", 1], ["c", 2], ["a", 3]]
> ```

This is very close. The first thing I would do is change the inner arrays to hashes:

```ruby
arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| { item => i }}
#=> [{ "a" => 0 }, { "b" => 1 }, { "c" => 2 }, { "a" => 3 }]
```

This is one step closer. Now, actually we want the indices in arrays:

```ruby
arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| { item => [i] }}
#=> [{ "a" => [0] }, { "b" => [1] }, { "c" => [2] }, { "a" => [3] }]
```

This is even closer. Now, all we need to do is to merge those hashes into one single hash. There is a method for that, which is called [`Hash#merge`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-merge). It takes an optional block for deconflicting duplicate keys, and all we need to do is concatenate the arrays:

```ruby
arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| { item => [i] }}.inject({}) {|acc, h| acc.merge(h) {|_, a, b| a + b } }
#=> { "a" => [0, 3], "b" => [1], "c" => [2] }
```

And we're done!

> How can I get my desired output in a functional way? I feel like it's something like
>
> ```
> Hash[arr.collect.with_index { |item, i| [item, item[i] << i || [i] }]
> ```
>
> But that doesn't yield anything.

Well, it has a `SyntaxError`, so obviously if it cannot even be parsed, then it cannot run, and if it doesn't even run, then it cannot possibly yield anything.

However, not that even *if* it worked, it would still violate your constraint that it should be done "in a functional way", because [`Array#<<`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-3C-3C) mutates its receiver and is thus not functional.

Comment: You are invoking `merge` on an array than on `Hash`

Comment: Could you go a little more into the inject part?

Answer (score 0):

```
 arr.map.with_index.each_with_object({}){ |(a, i), h| h[a] ? h[a] << i : (h[a] = [i]) }
 #=> {"a"=>[0, 3], "b"=>[1], "c"=>[2]}
```

`arr.map.with_index` => gives enumeration of each element with it's index

`each_with_object` => lets you reduce the enumeration on a provided object(represented by `h` in above)

Comment: `Array#<<` mutates its receiver, `Hash[]=` mutates its receiver, and `Enumerable#each_with_object` only works if you mutate the accumulator, so this is pretty much as "unfunctional" as it gets.